# curllib_static.lib error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol errors

Tags: c++

I'm using Visual Studios 2012 c++

I have already added 'the path to the lib file in Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories'

This was suggested here: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574400#12574400)

But that didn't work!

```
    Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSACleanup@0   C:\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(telnet.obj)   Win32Project8
    Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAStartup@8 referenced in function _win32_init    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(easy.obj)    Win32Project8
    Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAStartup@8   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(telnet.obj)  Win32Project8
    Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__closesocket@4 referenced in function _gmtime   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ftp.obj) Win32Project8
```

PS: I do already have a function '__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK handleinput(int code, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)' in my code. This is a necessary function.

EDIT 1:

Looks like it is still missing a crypto library.... After adding 'Ws2_32.lib' I still get those errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _RAND_file_name referenced in function _ossl_seed C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _RAND_screen referenced in function _ossl_seed    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _RAND_load_file referenced in function _ossl_seed C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _RAND_status referenced in function _rand_enough  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_library_init referenced in function _Curl_ossl_init  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_load_error_strings referenced in function _Curl_ossl_init    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data referenced in function _Curl_ossl_cleanup C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_cleanup referenced in function _Curl_ossl_cleanup    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_free_strings referenced in function _Curl_ossl_cleanup   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_peek referenced in function _Curl_ossl_check_cxn C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_get_error referenced in function _Curl_ossl_set_engine   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ENGINE_init referenced in function _Curl_ossl_set_engine C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ENGINE_free referenced in function _Curl_ossl_set_engine C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   14  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ENGINE_finish referenced in function _Curl_ossl_set_engine   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   15  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ENGINE_by_id referenced in function _Curl_ossl_set_engine    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   16  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_error_string_n referenced in function _SSL_strerror  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ENGINE_get_id referenced in function _Curl_ossl_set_engine_default   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   18  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ENGINE_set_default referenced in function _Curl_ossl_set_engine_default  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   19  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ENGINE_get_next referenced in function _Curl_ossl_engines_list   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   20  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ENGINE_get_first referenced in function _Curl_ossl_engines_list  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   21  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_free referenced in function _Curl_ossl_close C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   22  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_free referenced in function _Curl_ossl_close C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   23  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_set_connect_state referenced in function _Curl_ossl_close    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   24  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_shutdown referenced in function _Curl_ossl_close C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   25  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_error_string referenced in function _Curl_ossl_shutdown  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   26  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_error referenced in function _Curl_ossl_shutdown C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   27  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_read referenced in function _Curl_ossl_shutdown  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   28  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_SESSION_free referenced in function _Curl_ossl_session_free  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   29  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_remove_state referenced in function _Curl_ossl_close_all C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   30  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_set_fd referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   31  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_set_session referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   32  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_ctrl referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   33  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_new referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   34  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_set_verify referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   35  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_STORE_set_flags referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   36  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_load_crl_file referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   37  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_STORE_add_lookup referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1 C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   38  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_LOOKUP_file referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   39  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1 C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   40  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   41  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_ctrl referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   42  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_callback_ctrl referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1 C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   43  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_new referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   44  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv3_client_method referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   45  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv2_client_method referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   46  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TLSv1_client_method referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   47  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv23_client_method referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   48  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_PKEY_copy_parameters referenced in function _cert_stuff  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   49  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_privatekey referenced in function _cert_stuff    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   50  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_pubkey referenced in function _cert_stuff   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   51  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_certificate referenced in function _cert_stuff   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   52  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ENGINE_load_private_key referenced in function _cert_stuff   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   53  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _UI_OpenSSL referenced in function _cert_stuff    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   54  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file referenced in function _cert_stuff   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   55  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_add_client_CA referenced in function _cert_stuff C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   56  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sk_value referenced in function _cert_stuff  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   57  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sk_num referenced in function _cert_stuff    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   58  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_check_private_key referenced in function _cert_stuff C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   59  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey referenced in function _cert_stuff    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   60  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_free referenced in function _cert_stuff C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   61  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_PKEY_free referenced in function _cert_stuff C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   62  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_use_certificate referenced in function _cert_stuff   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   63  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PKCS12_free referenced in function _cert_stuff   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   64  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PKCS12_parse referenced in function _cert_stuff  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   65  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PKCS12_PBE_add referenced in function _cert_stuff    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   66  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _d2i_PKCS12_fp referenced in function _cert_stuff C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   67  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file referenced in function _cert_stuff  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   68  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file referenced in function _cert_stuff    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   69  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb referenced in function _cert_stuff C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   70  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata referenced in function _cert_stuff    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   71  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_subject_name referenced in function _cert_verify_callback   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   72  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert referenced in function _cert_verify_callback C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   73  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BIO_free referenced in function _x509_name_oneline   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   74  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BIO_ctrl referenced in function _x509_name_oneline   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   75  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_NAME_print_ex referenced in function _x509_name_oneline C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   76  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BIO_new referenced in function _x509_name_oneline    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   77  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BIO_s_mem referenced in function _x509_name_oneline  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   78  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CIPHER_get_name referenced in function _ossl_connect_step2   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   79  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_current_cipher referenced in function _ossl_connect_step2    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   80  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_connect referenced in function _ossl_connect_step2   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   81  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get1_session referenced in function _ossl_connect_step3  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   82  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_verify_cert_error_string referenced in function _servercert C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   83  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_verify_result referenced in function _servercert C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   84  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_check_issued referenced in function _servercert C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   85  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PEM_read_X509 referenced in function _servercert C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   86  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_issuer_name referenced in function _servercert  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   87  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_peer_certificate referenced in function _servercert  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   88  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_free referenced in function _verifyhost   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   89  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8 referenced in function _verifyhost   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   90  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_malloc referenced in function _verifyhost C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   91  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ASN1_STRING_type referenced in function _verifyhost  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   92  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data referenced in function _verifyhost  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   93  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_NAME_get_entry referenced in function _verifyhost   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   94  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID referenced in function _verifyhost    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   95  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GENERAL_NAMES_free referenced in function _verifyhost    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   96  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ASN1_STRING_length referenced in function _verifyhost    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   97  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ASN1_STRING_data referenced in function _verifyhost  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   98  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_ext_d2i referenced in function _verifyhost  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   99  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BN_bn2bin referenced in function _get_cert_chain C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   100 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BN_num_bits referenced in function _get_cert_chain   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   101 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_serialNumber referenced in function _get_cert_chain C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   102 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ASN1_INTEGER_get referenced in function _get_cert_chain  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   103 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_peer_cert_chain referenced in function _get_cert_chain   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   104 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _i2t_ASN1_OBJECT referenced in function _asn1_object_dump C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   105 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ASN1_STRING_print referenced in function _X509V3_ext C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   106 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509V3_EXT_print referenced in function _X509V3_ext  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   107 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_EXTENSION_get_critical referenced in function _X509V3_ext   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   108 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_EXTENSION_get_object referenced in function _X509V3_ext C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   109 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PEM_write_bio_X509 referenced in function _dumpcert  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   110 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_pending referenced in function _Curl_ossl_data_pending   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   111 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_write referenced in function _Curl_ossl_send C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   112 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLeay referenced in function _Curl_ossl_version C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj)  Win32Project8
Error   113 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_unbind_s referenced in function _Curl_ldap    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   114 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_msgfree referenced in function _Curl_ldap C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   115 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ber_free referenced in function _Curl_ldap C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   116 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_memfree referenced in function _Curl_ldap C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   117 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_value_free_len referenced in function _Curl_ldap  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   118 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_get_values_len referenced in function _Curl_ldap  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   119 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_next_attribute referenced in function _Curl_ldap  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   120 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_first_attribute referenced in function _Curl_ldap C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   121 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_get_dn referenced in function _Curl_ldap  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   122 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_next_entry referenced in function _Curl_ldap  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   123 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_first_entry referenced in function _Curl_ldap C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   124 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_search_s referenced in function _Curl_ldap    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   125 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_simple_bind_s referenced in function _Curl_ldap   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   126 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_init referenced in function _Curl_ldap    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   127 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_set_option referenced in function _Curl_ldap  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   128 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_err2string referenced in function _Curl_ldap  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ldap.obj)    Win32Project8
Error   129 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Final referenced in function _Curl_output_ntlm   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(http_ntlm.obj)   Win32Project8
Error   130 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Final    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(md5.obj) Win32Project8
Error   131 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Update referenced in function _Curl_output_ntlm  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(http_ntlm.obj)   Win32Project8
Error   132 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Update   C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(md5.obj) Win32Project8
Error   133 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Init referenced in function _Curl_output_ntlm    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(http_ntlm.obj)   Win32Project8
Error   134 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Init C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(md5.obj) Win32Project8
Error   135 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _RAND_bytes referenced in function _Curl_output_ntlm  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(http_ntlm.obj)   Win32Project8
Error   136 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DES_ecb_encrypt referenced in function _lm_resp  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(http_ntlm.obj)   Win32Project8
Error   137 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DES_set_key referenced in function _setup_des_key    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(http_ntlm.obj)   Win32Project8
Error   138 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DES_set_odd_parity referenced in function _setup_des_key C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(http_ntlm.obj)   Win32Project8
Error   139 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD4_Final referenced in function _mk_nt_hash C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(http_ntlm.obj)   Win32Project8
Error   140 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD4_Update referenced in function _mk_nt_hash    C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(http_ntlm.obj)   Win32Project8
Error   141 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD4_Init referenced in function _mk_nt_hash  C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(http_ntlm.obj)   Win32Project8
```

EDIT 2: After adding libeay32.lib, openldap.lib and ssleay32.lib, I get tons of errors like:

curllib_static.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Debug\vc90.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info

What is 'vc90.pdb' and where do I download it?

Comment: have you added also library name in linker->input->additional dependencies?

Comment: @Jepessen Yes, it is set to: **curllib_static.lib**;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Comment: These look like OpenSSL symbols, you'll probably need to link that in too.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths See Edit 2 I still can't run the .exe It says application configuration is incorrect.

Comment: @user10056: Did you google any of this stuff? These messages show up all over the place, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460623/pdb-vc100-pdb-was-not-found-with)

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I can't run the .exe because it shows an error box saying that the configuration is incorrect and ask to review the manifest file

Comment: @user10056: Based on the information you have provided, which is basically zero, I have no idea how your project is incorrectly configured, no. Did you check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235229.aspx)? Your IDE comes with documentation, you ought to be reading it.

Answer (score 4):

You must also link Winsock, i.e. `Ws2_32.lib`.

Comment: 1) Why? 2) It only removed 50 of the 200 errors. See edited question above. Now I still get: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _RAND_file_name referenced in function _ossl_seed C:\Projects\Win32Project8\Win32Project8\curllib_static.lib(ssluse.obj) Win32Project8

Comment: @user10056 I've googled for `WSACleanup` and a MSDN link came up. There Ws2_32.lib was listed as a requirement. As to `.pdb` - it's a debug information database generated by VS, you don't need it for your application to work, but you won't be able to do stuff like stepping into curl's code with VS debugger, etc.